# How do I query for all dates greater than a certain date in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm trying:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.March2010 A
WHERE A.Date >= 2010-04-01;
```

`A.Date` looks like: `2010-03-04 00:00:00.000`

However, this is not working.

Can anyone provide a reference for why?

Comment: put single quotes around it

Comment: In addition to quotes, I recommend always using a safe and unambiguous format for date-only string literals. The only one I trust is YYYYMMDD. See my comment to David's answer for the reason why...

Answer (score 664, accepted):

```
select *  
from dbo.March2010 A 
where A.Date >= Convert(datetime, '2010-04-01' )
```

In your query, `2010-4-01` is treated as a mathematical expression, so in essence it read

```
select *  
from dbo.March2010 A 
where A.Date >= 2005;
```

(`2010 minus 4 minus 1 is 2005`
Converting it to a proper `datetime`, and using single quotes will fix this issue.)

Technically, the parser might allow you to get away with

```
select *  
from dbo.March2010 A 
where A.Date >= '2010-04-01'
```

it will do the conversion for you, but in my opinion it is less readable than explicitly converting to a `DateTime` for the maintenance programmer that will come after you.

Comment: The explicit convert is not necessary. Also I highly recommend using YYYYMMDD instead of YYYY-MM-DD. Why? Well, try your code with `SET LANGUAGE FRENCH`. :-) For that date you'll get January 4 instead of April 1. For other dates you might get an error instead.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrant - My answer did include that the conversion isn't necessary, starting with "Techically, the pareser might let you get away with <final code sample>.  I just find it more readable, because it's strikingly obvious that this is a date-time.  Too many Database Systems store date values in a varchar field, but you're right about the format.  Normally, when using conversion I add in the format specifier as well, but I was doing my sample off the top of my head.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I had to use your suggestion in conjuction with the above answer: `CONVERT(datetime, '20100401 10:01:01')` - passing 2010-04-01 works in SQL Server Management Studio but not when sending the SQL statement via PHP/MSSQL.

Comment: I think it's clear enough that this is a date, and thus conversion is not necessary.

Comment: I wasn't able to use the `Convert(datetime, '2010-04-01' )` in BigQuery . If anyone looking to execute greater than date function in BigQuery , you can follow the answer mentioned in the link below [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51270266)

Answer (score 87):

Try enclosing your date into a character string.

```
 select * 
 from dbo.March2010 A
 where A.Date >= '2010-04-01';
```

Comment: Adding time will give exact result : where A.Date >= 2014-01-12 12:28:00

Answer (score 28):

We can use like below as well

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.March2010 A
WHERE CAST(A.Date AS Date) >= '2017-03-22';

SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.March2010 A
    WHERE CAST(A.Date AS Datetime) >= '2017-03-22 06:49:53.840';
```

Comment: Modifying the filter predicate column is not a good idea whatsoever. It prevents index usage almost entirely.

Answer (score 22):

In your query you didn't use single quote around date. That was the problem. However,
you can use any of the following query to compare date

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.March2010 A
WHERE A.Date >= '2010-04-01';


SELECT * 
FROM dbo.March2010 A
WHERE A.Date >= CAST('2010-04-01' as Date);


SELECT *  
FROM dbo.March2010 A 
WHERE A.Date >= Convert(datetime, '2010-04-01' )
```

Answer (score 10):

To sum it all up, the correct answer is :

```
select * from db where Date >= '20100401'  (Format of date yyyymmdd)
```

This will avoid any problem with other language systems and will use the index.

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime start1 = DateTime.Parse(txtDate.Text);

SELECT * 
FROM dbo.March2010 A
WHERE A.Date >= start1;
```

First convert TexBox into the Datetime then....use that variable into the Query

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert both the dates in same format before conversion

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.March2010 A
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, A.Date) >= 2010-04-01;
```

Answer (score 0):

The date format has no issue with me(`Mydate`'s data type is `datetime`) :
`Where Mydate>'10/25/2021'` or `Where Mydate>'2021-10-25'`
but if add a time, above answers are not working.
Here is what I do:
`where cast(Mydate as time)>'22:00:00'`
If your query needs a date, please add date such as:
`where cast(Mydate as time)>'22:00:00' and Mydate='10/25/2021'`