# T-SQL filtering by date in dd/mm/yyy format

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In T-SQL is there a way to filter by greater than a date given in dd/mm/yyyy format?

so for example:

```
SELECT BIRTHDAY FROM ATABLE WHERE BIRTHDAY > 12/12/1990
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643379/how-do-i-query-for-all-dates-greater-than-a-certain-date-in-sql-server

Comment: 12/12/1990 would yield 0, due to integer math.

Comment: So I've got to ask why do you care what the date format is for a `WHERE` clause? 1/1/1991 is greater than 12/12/1990 no matter how you format it...

Comment: This is difficult to know how to answer without knowing the collation settings, the data type in the table, and your regional settings as well. Can you please post this information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since many date formats are dependent on language & regional settings, I recommend to **always** use the ISO-8601 format of `YYYYMMDD` - and of course, also put your date literal into **single quotes**:

```
SELECT Birthday
FROM dbo.ATable 
WHERE Birtday > '19901212'
```

This works on all SQL Servers - regardless of what language, date and regional settings you have