# Database: delete specific data

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have some columns in "user" table like name , email , country, last_online  ,as example :

```
> Mohamed , email , UAE , 2014-06-24 21:43:16
> 
> Ali , email , LY , 2013-05-18 07:13:56
> 
> Zeyad , email , EG , 2011-04-12 19:52:23
```

i want delete users data whom never logged since 2011-01-01 ,How can i do it ?

Comment: What exactly seems to be a problem?

Comment: Study up. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643379/how-do-i-query-for-all-dates-greater-than-a-certain-date-in-sql-server may be of help. Once you're happy with your select query, you can change it to a delete: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Comment: `delete from user where last_login <= '2011-01-01'`

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid this will delete which users ? below 2011  or above ?

Comment: First try `select * from user where last_login <= '2011-01-01'`.  See the results that you're given.  Understand why you get the results you do.  Then, change the `select *` to `delete` and rerun the query.  The rows that came up in the `select` will be the same rows that are `delete`d.

Comment: Thanks @Andy Lester , you can copy it as answer so i mark it right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic delete statement is all that you need:

```
delete from user where last_online <= '2011-01-01'
```

You should try to read up on basic SQL syntax.