# In orientDB, how to search entries for which date are in a given year?

Tags: date, orientdb, jbake

In my OrientDB instance, entries have `date` property which is stored as a `java.util.Date`.

I would like to get all documents written on a given year. But I don't think writing

```
SELECT FROM posts WHERE date.format('yyyy')=2012
```

Is the best way to do. or is it ?

Comment: Well I think for those things, especially years, it's way better to use clustering.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I query for all dates greater than a certain date in sql server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643379/how-do-i-query-for-all-dates-greater-than-a-certain-date-in-sql-server)

Comment: It can easily be rewritten as a date greater than or lower than using previously mentionned question, so I close mine.

Comment: Oh, no, inf act, it's a SQL question, and not an OrientDB one ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given query is very inefficient, a full table scan will be performed. Best is to use (a possible index can be used):

```
select from posts where date between '2012-01-01 00:00:00' and '2012-12-31 23:59:59'
```

Assumption: date is of type Date(Time)

Comment: Orientdb internally stores dates as unixTime, meaning its just a "long" number.