# Not able to fetch records by Date from database

Tags: sql-server, database

[image]

I have data based on column id and date...Data Type for date is DATETIME

DataBase : sql server 2008

Query 1:

```
Select * 
from table t1 
where (t1.date between '2016-05-11' and  '2016-05-13')
```

Query 2:

```
select * 
from table t1 
where t1.date IN ('2016-05-11')
```

Result is **NUll** even i have records on this date

So is there any Alternative to fetch records **except** (**<=**/**<**/**>**/**>=**) greater than or less than

Comment: please use Select * from table t1 where (t1.date between '2016-05-11' and '2016-05-13')

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643379/how-do-i-query-for-all-dates-greater-than-a-certain-date-in-sql-server

Comment: @ChetanSanghani your query is ame as Query 1,and i am not getting any records

Comment: there is missing one single quote in your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below query but your query is also correct and its running on my server.

```
Select * from table t1 
where t1.date between '20160511 00:00:00' and '20160513 23:59:59';

select * from table t1 where cast(t1.date as date) IN ('20160511');
```

Comment: it is working if I have Data Type "date" in database....but not working with Data Type "datetime"

Comment: Which server version you are using?

Comment: sql server 2008 R2

Comment: On SQL server 2008 R2 , I have tested and its running.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Select * 
from table t1 
where cast(t1.date as date) between '2016-05-11' and  '2016-05-13'
```

ie Convert your datetime column to date and compare, because your parameters are only date values.
or

```
where cast(t1.date as date) in ('2016-05-11')--For your second query
```

or use greater than or less than

```
Select * 
from table t1 
where t1.date >= '2016-05-11' and  t1.date < '2016-05-14'
```

Comment: @TomTom : What about this answer??

Comment: @Abdul Rasheed, casting query is working if I have Data Type "Date" in database....but not working with Data Type "datetime".

Comment: if you are not getting result for the query - where cast(t1.date as date) between '2016-05-11' and  '2016-05-13' , then there should be no records in this period.

Comment: See the Image....in question...there is 3 records available between  '2016-05-11' and '2016-05-13'...Query is running successfully but data fetch result is Null

Comment: then chk - where t1.date >= '2016-05-11' and  t1.date < '2016-05-14'? Yes it is t1.date < '2016-05-14'

Comment: I know that but finding other alternative

Comment: And what about IN query...which is Query 2

Comment: IN query will not work for u , bcs it is exact match (your time fraction also will be same  then only u wll get the result). r u getting the expected result in >= and < query?