# Excel [Expression.Error] We cannot apply operator < to types Text and Date

Tags: vba, excel

I have been searching for several days now (as a total noob).

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim SellStartDate As Date 'Declare the SellStartDate as Date
Dim SellEndDate As Date 'Declare the SellEndDate as Date
SellStartDate = Sheets("Summary").Range("C3").Value   'Pass value from 
cell B3 to SellStartDate variable
SellEndDate = Sheets("Summary").Range("C4").Value    'Pass value from 
cell B4 to SellEndDate variable
'Pass the Parameters values to the Stored Procedure used in the Data 
Connection
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - storm sales 
(2)").OLEDBConnection
.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [storm sales (2)] WHERE ADVICEDATE >= 
'&SellStartDate&' AND ADVICEDATE <= '&SellEndDate&'"
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - storm sales (2)").Refresh
End With
End Sub
```

The above code was based on an item found elsewhere on the internet.

It passes the values to the CommandText if you use `=` or `!=` but not if you use anything containing `<` or `>`

The error I get is

> [Expression.Error] We cannot apply operator < to types Text and Date

What I am asking is what would give me the same result as `>=` and `<=` without the error.

Thanks in advance,

Neil.

Comment: You could try to convert the dates in your sql query.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643379/how-do-i-query-for-all-dates-greater-than-a-certain-date-in-sql-server

Comment: Thanks @Mortaliar - Yes I had tried that one but it gives me;
Run-time error '1004':
The command 'SELECT * FROM [storm sales (2)] WHERE ADVICEDATE >= Convert(datetime , &SellStartDate&)' isn't supported.

Comment: Also tried Convert(datetime , '&SellStartDate&'), Convert(datetime , 'SellStartDate'), Convert(date , '&SellStartDate&'), etc which give:
[DataFormat.Error] We couldn't parse the input as a Date value.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try the conversion with apostrophes in the query?

```
Convert(datetime , &SellStartDate&)

Convert(datetime ,' &SellStartDate& ')
```

This is how SQL converts with and without the apostrophes.

```
Convert(datetime, '2010-04-01' ) -> 2010-04-01 00:00:00.000

Convert(datetime, 2010-04-01 ) -> 1905-06-29 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Thank you for replying again, it is appreciated. Yes I tried with and without both ' and & for date and datetime. Alas all leading to the same end, not parsing.

Comment: It could be the matter of how the date is stored in a particular cell. Did you run a simple select on just the value you're passing?  
"SELECT &SellEndDate&"

Comment: Run-time error '1004':
The command 'SELECT &SellStartDate&' isn't supported

Ifr this helps 
SELECT ADVICEDATE = '&SellStartDate&'

returns ADVICEDATE in the header row of the sheet with &SellStartDate& in the cell underneath.

Comment: What I can't get my head around is that = and != work but > and < don't. Am I missing something here?

Comment: What is the datatype of ADVICEDATE in your SQL table? 
It is possible it's not a date or datetime, thus you'd have to convert ADVICEDATE as well.

Comment: I just double checked and can confirm it is a date.