# Athena greater than condition in date column

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I have the following query that I am trying to run on Athena.

```
SELECT observation_date, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM db.table_name
WHERE observation_date > '2017-12-31'
GROUP BY observation_date
```

However it is producing this error:

```
SYNTAX_ERROR: line 3:24: '>' cannot be applied to date, varchar(10)
```

This seems odd to me. Is there an error in my query or is Athena not able to handle greater than operators on date columns?

Thanks!

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You need to use a cast to format the date correctly before making this comparison. Try the following:

```
SELECT observation_date, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM db.table_name
WHERE observation_date > CAST('2017-12-31' AS DATE)
GROUP BY observation_date
```

Check it out in Fiddler: [SQL Fidle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0713b/3)

***UPDATE 17/07/2019***

In order to reflect comments

```
SELECT observation_date, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM db.table_name
WHERE observation_date > DATE('2017-12-31')
GROUP BY observation_date
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this does not solve the issue. That column is already a date class, I expect this is an issue specific to Amazon Athena databases. Your linked fiddle I can see is set to MS SQL Server, a different flavour of SQL in which your answer would be a valid solution.

Comment: @efbbrown The error you have quoted is a syntax error. I doubt it is an Athena issue. Basically the two sides you're evaluating are not the same format. Without specific information about your table (a create statement would be helpful) I guessed that your date column was formatted as a timestamp. If you're sure that your date is in the correct format, then you need to format the right hand side of the evaluation as a date.

Comment: Thanks Barry, you were totally right. I needed to cast the RHS of my evaluation to date. `WHERE observation_date > CAST('2017-12-31' AS DATE)`.

Comment: Glad I could help. Updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Instead of a CAST, I would use a DATE literal: `DATE '2017-12-31'` like in `WHERE observation_date > DATE '2017-12-31'`.

Answer (score 21):

You can also use the [date](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html) function which is a convenient alias for `CAST(x AS date)`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM date_data
WHERE trading_date >= DATE('2018-07-06');
```

Answer (score 3):

I just want to add my little words here, if you have date column with [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, for example: `2022-08-02T01:46:46.963120Z` then you can use [parse_datetime](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/presto-functions.html) function.

In my case, the query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM internal_alb_logs
WHERE elb_status_code >= 500 AND parse_datetime(time,'yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS''Z') > parse_datetime('2022-08-01-23:00:00','yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss')
ORDER BY time DESC
```

See more other examples here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/application-load-balancer-logs.html#query-alb-logs-examples

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from my_schema.my_table_name where date_column = cast('2017-03-29' as DATE) limit 5
```