# SQL query that will show all the codes where the average number of transfer among users in that code is less than two

Tags: sql

```
User
|uid|admin|match_id|code|
|152|0    |NULL    |PH     |
|66 |1    |2212    |US     |
|66 |0    |1234    |AL     |
|66 |0    |2221    |AL     |


Transfer
|eid|transfer_at|match_id|
|284|2018-11-29 |2001    |
|284|2018-11-30 |2023    |
|284|2018-12-03 |2023    |
```

When two users are transferred together, they become a 'transfer'. Every transfer has TWO users. One user can have multiple matches.

When two users complete a transfer, a row is added to the transfer table.

Result Expected -  codes where the average number of transfer among users in that code is less than two

```
|code|
|PH     |
|US     |
|BR     |
```

Comment: Tables and sample data should be shown as `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` statements, not as images. Desired result and the query you've tried so far are also missing. See: [Example]

Comment: You should only tag relevant DBMS. I removed the tags. Please add only the one of your DBMS.

Comment: And there's no question here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I query for all dates greater than a certain date in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643379/how-do-i-query-for-all-dates-greater-than-a-certain-date-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First left join `exchange` to `user` and use aggregation to get the number of matches per user. Then aggegate again to get the average number of matches per country.

```
SELECT x.country
       FROM (SELECT u.uid,
                    u.country,
                    count(e.eid) matches
                    FROM user u
                         LEFT JOIN exchange e
                                   ON e.match_id = u.match_id
                    GROUP BY u.uid,
                             u.country) x
       GROUP BY x.country
       HAVING avg(x.matches) < 2;
```