# Spotfire information designer- restrict data by date syntax

Tags: date, spotfire

I am trying to find the correct syntax for restricting data before a given date in the information designer view
The filed is a date time field, the code I am using is > 31/12/2020 I get the error "invalid filter", I have tried Column ">Datetime.now()-1095".
Any help for this I am sure simple matter would be appreciated.

Tony

Answer (score 0):

Using the inline filters in the information link can be a little quirky at times. It is not clear where you specify the filter from your question.

Consider using filter element and use the datetime column as reference becomming %1.
Next look up SQL syntax for the data source you are querying.

That would result in a expression like:  %1 >= Convert(datetime, '20100401' )

[Anwer for datetime larger than.. SQL Server on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643379/how-do-i-query-for-all-dates-greater-than-a-certain-date-in-sql-server)
[Sql shack on conversion functions](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-functions-for-converting-string-to-date/)